# I don't understand the alternative definition of $\mathrm{gr}(R)$ in Kemper, A Course in Commutative Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

In Kemper, *A Course in Commutative Algebra* there is an alternative definition of associated graded ring, as shown below.

Let $R$ be a Noetherian local ring with maximal ideal $m$.
    $$R^{*}:=R[m\cdot t]\subset R[t]$$
    $$R_{d}^{*}:=R\cdot t^{d} \cap R^{*}=m^{d}\cdot t^{d}$$
    $$\mathrm{gr}(R):=R^{*}/(m)_{R^{*}}$$
    $$\mathrm{gr}(R)_{d}:=R_{d}^{*}/(R_{d}^{*}\cdot m)\cong m^{d}/m^{d+1}$$
    then 
    $\mathrm{gr}(R)=\bigoplus_{d\in \mathbb{N}} \mathrm{gr}(R)_{d}$.

But I don't understand why $\mathrm{gr}(R)$ defined in this way can be decomposed as direct sum like this. I don't see a clear inclusion here and I think it's not clear how to define multiplication in this way (like in the definition of graded ring, $S_{i}\cdot S_{j}\subset S_{i+j}$). Could you please show me in detail how $\mathrm{gr}(R)$ is decomposed into direct sum of $\mathrm{gr}(R)_{d}$ and the isomorphism in the fourth line?

Comment: Should we guess what book is GTM256?

Comment: I don't know what means $(m)_{R^*}$, but it should be $mR^*$, that is, the extension of $m$ to the Rees algebra $R^*$.

Comment: @user26857 my apologies. It's Gregor Kemper's A course in commutative algebra, on page170

Comment: @user26857 yes it does

Comment: Think like this: $R^*=\oplus_nm^nt^n$ and $mR^*=\oplus_nm^{n+1}t^n$. Then $R^*/mR^*=\oplus_nm^nt^n/\oplus_nm^{n+1}t^n=\oplus_nm^nt^n/m^{n+1}t^n$. Now get rid of $t$ in every graded piece.